# ValueError when fitting subclassed scipy distribution

Tags: python, scipy, distribution, data-fitting, scipy.stats

I'm trying to subclass `rv_continuous` from `scipy.stats` in order to implement the 3 parameter log-normal distribution. I've only re-implemented the `_pdf` method so far just to see if I can get a minimal example running:

```
from scipy import stats
from math import sqrt, pi, exp, log, e


class LogNormal3P(stats.rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self, x, alpha, m, sigma):
        return 1 / (sigma * (x - alpha) * sqrt(2 * pi)) * exp(-(log(x - alpha, e) - m)**2 / (2 * sigma**2))


lognorm3p = LogNormal3P(name='lognorm3p')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import numpy as np

    data = np.array([16.66, 28.0, 14.3, 15.99, 16.26, 22.69, 19.1, 14.82, 13.91, 11.1])

    ln3p = lognorm3p.fit(data)

    print('Done')
```

When running this code I get the error `ValueError: math domain error`. This is because on the first iteration of the fitting process a point is reached where, x = -11 and the value of the other parameters are equal to 1. This causes a negative value in the log function resulting in the error.

What is the typical work-around for this? None of the data values are negative so I'm assuming this happens during a normalization step. Am I missing any methods of `rv_continuous` that should be re-implemented prior to trying to fit the data? The documentation mentions that either `_pdf` or `_cdf` should be re-implemented at a minimum.

Comment: It's not a normalization step that causes the issue, it looks like the CDF is being evaluated over some range like `[-10, 10]`. I'm a bit confused as to how fitting this distribution would work, though, with the `alpha` parameter. Its valid range is dependent on the input data `x`, right? So on each fit iteration, the optimizer would need a potentially different valid range for `alpha` and/or for the support `x`. How would that work?

Comment: But in any case, you might try reimplementing the `_argcheck` or `_get_support` methods, or setting the, to constrain the search space for the optimizer. I'm still not sure how you could write such a method, though, since on each iteration different ranges alpha are acceptable for different parts of the support. You might also set `a` and `b` on initialization, the lower/upper ranges of the support, respectively.

Comment: Also, your alpha and sigma seem to be loc and scale, so should not be arguments to _pdf

Comment: @ev-br I was thinking that as well. So if the only argument is `m` (probably the shape parameter in this case), scipy will handle loc and scale internally? I'd still need all 3 parameters to be returned from the fit

Comment: It will, yes. Unless you make it fixed via floc=... parameter